# How to create custom abstract repository like PagingAndSortingRepository, etc?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For example in my persistence:

```
public interface SomePersistence extends JpaRepository<SomeClass, String> {};
```

I can write method like: 
`@Query("some query")
List<SomeClass> getAllWithSomeParam();`

and spring knows to use SimpleJpaRepository class - implementation of JpaRepository.

When i write: 
`@Query("some query")
Page<SomeClass> getAllWithSomeParam(Pageable page);`

spring knows to use implementation of PagingAndSortingRepository.

But now i want to add my own returned type - `Cursor<T>`

It`s mean i want write:

```
@Query("some query")
Cursor<SomeClass> anyMethodName();
```

Then i want to give spring my own repository CursorRepository with its personal CursorRepositoryImpl when i have only one method `Cursor<T> findAll()`

Can i realize it?

Comment: I guess you can not do it. You have to decide between List<T>, Slice<T>, or Page<T>. Otherwise you have to implement repository on your own. Why not using Page instead of your Cursor?

Comment: Yeap, ofcourse i can use pagination, but i wont to create more abstract method. In cursor i don`t need to implement paginate loop, i had something like this: ScrollableResults rs = session.createQuery(query).scroll(FORWARD_ONLY);

And Cursor is my implementation of Iterator, where hasNext() {rs.next();)
and next() {rs.get(0);}

Comment: IMHO your case is not covered by capabilities of Spring Data.

Comment: Thanks @DamienMiheev. Your question held the answer to my query. Use pageable within custom Repository query. `@Query("some query")
Page<SomeClass> getAllWithSomeParam(Pageable page);`